# Docker containers on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, virtual-machine, containers

With Docker you can build, run, test and distribute applications that are based on Linux Containers. According to my understanding, Docker containers are lighter than virtual machines, and are designed as a substitute to them.

[Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) (and I am sure that other cloud providers too) uses Docker images in task definitions to launch containers on EC2 instances in my clusters. My questions are the following:

1. Are these containers launched on top of Virtual Machines?
2. If yes, doesn't that beat the purpose of having Docker in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Yes!

2 - As a Linux Container engine rather than traditional virtualization methods....the Docker uses the same host server kernel, making everything very fast.

A container is an isolated and mobile process through namespaces + chroot. So do the "start" of a container is very fast (it's as fast as start a new process).

So, using containers ... you can get the requirements for a much easier process and no chances to get conflict with any requirement of another process.

I hope this helps.